# Launch program on startup in background

Tags: 18.04, startup, startup-applications

I'm running AutoKey on Ubuntu 18.04, I added it to the startup applications, but I don't want its window pops up after starting my computer, can I make it launch in the background?

Answer (score 5):

To start an application at start up and put it in the background simply append `&` to the command you wish to execute.

An example using AutoKey:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting the correct answer, I'll delete my *wrong* answer.

Comment: That's quite nice of you, and I think a good example of SO ideals :) some people just abandon answers that were not accurate or in some cases even introduce security flaws, so, thank you too

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Gnome's "Tweaks" tool to put it into autostart: Edit  `~/.config/autostart/autokey.desktop` to remove the `-c` flag from the `Exec` line. It should then look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AutoKey
GenericName=Keyboard Automation
Comment=Program keyboard shortcuts
Exec=autokey-gtk
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=autokey
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
```

(You can also just create that file without using any GUI tools.)